# Tkinter program runs function but the window pops up after it ends

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Ok so I'm pretty new to tkinter and I can not solve this problem that I am having.

When I run the program, it runs the function and after it ends the window with the photo pops up, but the loop does not start the program again.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*
from PIL import ImageTk,Image 
from tkinter import messagebox
import YuaChanMainFunc
import time

def on_click(event=None):
    # `command=` calls function without argument
    # `bind` calls function with one argument
    print("Hey Yua!")
    YuaChanMainFunc.statement="hey yua"

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        master.title("Yua-chan AI")
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("YuaChanAI/Yua Chan Artwork/YuaChan2.png"))
        MainLB = tk.Label(master, image=self.img)
        MainLB.bind('<Button-1>', on_click)
        MainLB.pack()
        b = tk.Button(root, text="Close", command=root.destroy)
        b.pack()



#YuaChanMainFunc.YuaChanAIMainFunc()
root = tk.Tk()
#instance of the class
app = Window(root)
root.resizable(0,0)
root.geometry("310x500+1600+510")
YuaChanMainFunc.YuaChanAIMainFunc()
#Runs the application until we close
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want "YuaChanMainFunc.YuaChanAIMainFunc()"
to run in the background while UI runs the foreground. For that you can start the "YuaChanMainFunc.YuaChanAIMainFunc()" in a different thread and run UI in the main thread itself. Now you can make "YuaChanMainFunc.YuaChanAIMainFunc()" an infinite loop and it wont block root.mainloop(). Also keep in mind root.mainloop() is also an infinite loop. SO anything you write after that will not execute until you close the program.

```
import threading
backend_thread = threading.Thread(target=YuaChanMainFunc.YuaChanAIMainFunc, args=())
backend_thread.daemon = True  #This will make sure backend thread closes when you close ui
backend_thread.start()
root.mainloop()
```